# How to save all pixels that were in the place of a rect in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Is there a way to save all the pixels that were in the place of a rect before drawing it? So that when I draw that rect again in a different place I can replace the old one with the saved pixels instead of filling that area with colors mamually?

Comment: What do you mean by rect? Do you mean a `pygame.Rect`? Or just a rectangular area on your screen? Is the area previously drawn by some command or have you filled the pixels manually? Could you give an example in code? Because a "rect with pixels" is just a `pygame.Surface`, and blitting it anywhere on the screen shouldn't be a problem. So an example would showcase your problem more clearly.

Comment: @Rabbid76 It is solved yep. I forgot to say thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a subsurface that is directly linked to the source surface with the method [`subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface):

> `subsurface(Rect) -> Surface`
>
> Returns a new Surface that shares its pixels with its new parent. The new Surface is considered a child of the original. Modifications to either Surface pixels will effect each other.

Create a [copy](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.copy) of the subsurface to store it permanently:

```py
rect_area = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
area_surf = screen.subsurface(rect_area).copy()
```

Use the *Surface* later to replace the rectangular area:

```py
screen.blit(area_surf, region)
```